# Операции просмотра в районе этого макроса могут привести к сбою. Добавьте его в файл указании

Tags: c++

Testclass.h

```
#pragma once
class Test
{
private:
    int x;
public:
    int getX() { return x; }
    Test(const int &x) :x(x) {}
    int operator + (const Test &object);
};
```

Testclass.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Testclass.h"


int Test::operator + (const Test &object)
{
    return x + object.x;
}
```

Test.cpp

```
#include "catch.hpp"
#include "Testclass.h"

TEST_CASE("Testing Sample Class") {
...
    Test a(5), b(6);
    SECTION("test addition") {
    ...
        REQUIRE(a + b == 11);
        ...
    }
}
```

После запуска вот такая ошибка:

```
1>------ Сборка начата: проект: 4TEST, Конфигурация: Debug Win32 ------
1>Testclass.cpp
1>LINK : fatal error LNK1561: точка входа должна быть определена
1>Сборка проекта "4TEST.vcxproj" завершена с ошибкой.
========== Сборка: успешно: 0, с ошибками: 1, без изменений: 0, пропущено: 0 ==========
```

Comment: Из какой библиотеки `catch.hpp`?

Comment: Что за странный заголовок??

Comment: @freim Это сообщение от intellisense когда оно не может найти типоопределения для макросов. А catch - сплошная макросопомойка.

Comment: [Вот](https://github.com/catchorg/Catch2/) @HolyBlackCat

Answer (score 1):

Если вы не определяете точку входа самостоятельно, то это следует поручить фреймворку. Для этого достаточно объявить директиву препроцессора `CATCH_CONFIG_MAIN` в одной из единиц трансляции перед включением заголовочного файла фреймворка.

Comment: Создал новый .cpp файл, сделал так как вы и сказали. Но вылезло много ошибок LNK2019

Comment: @ANurbaev Но ошибка, представленная в вопросе, больше не появляется?

Comment: Переделал код. Ошибки исчезли. Программа запускается, но консоль быстро исчезает. Удалось разглядеть All tests passed ..., хотя там не все тесты должны были пройти. Мне новый вопрос создавать? @VTT

Comment: @ANurbaev Да, ведь это какая-то другая проблема. И не надо было этот править.